# android dynamically change Text colour to an xml file

Tags: android, xml

I can change my background colours dynamically using prechosen colour very easily

```
myButton.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("@color/white"));
```

However how do I do that for text colour?

```
year_clicked.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
```

Comment: year_clicked means your Textview or what else

Comment: you can try with `ContextCompat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
year_clicked.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

as JinalPatel suggested use ContextCombat if you have support library added

```
year_clicked.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
```

Comment: getResources().getColor() is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
year_clicked.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is not very verbose about this, but you cannot use just the `R.color` integer when calling `setTextColor`. You need to call `getResources().getColor(R.color.YOURCOLOR)` to set a color properly.

Use the following to set color of your text programmatically:

```
year_clicked.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YOURCOLOR));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `ContextCompat` for better approach

### Why

**<s>getResources().getColor()</s>**   is deprecated on **Android 6.0 Marshmallow (API 23)**.

So try with

```
setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.Your_color));
```